# how to dont save a empty input django and why is not showing data on admin page?

Tags: python, django

how to don't save a empty input django and why is not showing data on admin page ?
because when i try to click on myhtml page is save the empty column every click and save it on my data base , how to stop saving the empty input or don't allow user input the empty input ?

and why i cant see the datetimefield on admin page ??
this my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Name
from django.shortcuts import redirect

# Create your views here.

def Home(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            Name.objects.create(massenger_name=request.POST['user_name'])
            return redirect(Home)
        return render(request , 'index.html')
```

and this mosels.py

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.

class Name(models.Model):
    massenger_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    action_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.massenger_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your models.py action_time() null needs to be false, and blank needs to be false. Before making this change make sure that you delete all instances that are blank/null.

Comment: its still doesn't work

Comment: Can you be more specific, what is not working?